# Are answers that are just links Answers?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed, answers

Many times the answer to someone's problem can be found at one of the other excellent Android sites out there on the WWWeb. Rather than recreate the wheel, the simplest thing to do is just give a link to this other content.

Is an answer that is (mostly) just a link to an outside source useful?

If not, what should be done about such answers?

Comment: The downside to this is when the links eventually break. I think linking is OK but maybe a short summary or key highlights would be even better than just a link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/154510)

I have nothing to say that devinb's answer doesn't as far as link-only answers being bad.

As for what to do with them, see the FAQ:

> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are [..] barely more than a link to an external site

I delete such answers in egregious cases, but when there's something important buried in the link or the answerer made *some* effort I encourage them to edit and summarize the content behind the link.

Comment: I suggest that the link is probably helpful and so the answer should be converted to a comment rather than outright deleted. Otherwise I agree with you and devinb. ***Raw links are not answers.***

Comment: For sure, yes :)

Comment: The winds blowing in from Meta Stack Overflow are that answers that don't have any useful information besides a link are not answers and should, at best, be converted to a comment. This is further reinforced by the Low Quality Review Queue which offers as one of its delete auto-comments "this is just a link and not an answer" (paraphrased).